# Open Port or not?

Tags: router

I opened a port in a router and forwarded it to a Universal Devices ISY (lightin computer).  (eg Port 4444 forwared by the router to 192.168.1.210).  I don't have the ISY computer plugged into the router - it is disconnected.  When I use an internet port checker to look at my router external IP followed by the port, it shows the port as closed (eg. 75.157.xxx.xxx:4444).  Is it showing the port as closed because I don't have the ISY computer connected to the router?

Comment: There's no response from the port, so as far as anyone knows, it's closed.

Answer (score 2):

In order for a Network Address Translation feature to function properly, the router must pass along attempts to establish a connection to a device behind the router.  The router can't establish a connection if there's no device on its LAN side to complete the TCP handshake.

Now, whether it's showing the port closed because that's how it's programmed to handle port mappings that do not have a target host, or if that's how it handles all connection attempts is for you to determine, by scanning on other ports, and to see how your router behaves differently for ports that aren't configured.